# C# Dapper QueryFirstOrDefault method with "The method or operation is not implemented" exception

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a static method like

```
public static DataRow query_result_to_DataRow()
    {
        DataTable _dt = null;
        using (IDbConnection dbConn = dkCommon.dbConn)
        {
            dbConn.Open();
            try
            {
                _dt = dbConn.QueryFirstOrDefault<DataTable>("select * from tbl_dk_users where user_name like 'admin' and user_pass like '123456'");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
        DataRow _dr = _dt.Rows[0];
        return _dr;
    }
```

I have exception "Method or operation is not implemented" exception in code

```
_dt = dbConn.QueryFirstOrDefault<DataTable>(_query, null, null, 600000, null);
```

Method of dapper QueryFirstOrDefault can't return any data. I don't know where am I wrong...

Comment: `QueryFirstOrDefault` is in the Dapper namespace, have you made sure you have implemented the appropriate using declaration ?

Comment: `QueryFirstOrDefault<DataTable>` gives exactly the error described in the question. The reason is that dapper does not have a way of mapping the resulting `Anonymous` on to `DataTable`. There is no need to. Either use the non-strongly-typed version of `QueryFirstOrDefault` and get the values you need from the `Anonymous`, or create a class with Properties matching the columns you're interested in and use that, like `QueryFirstOrDefault<MyClass>(...`

Comment: There are a couple of other problems with your code. You are using a connection created elsewhere in a `using` block. At the end of that block the connection will be `Dispose`d and next time you try to use it there will be an exception. Create a new connection every time. Also you catch an exception, then carry on, leaving `_dt` as null which will then throw an exception when you access its members without checking for null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to retrieve a `DataTable` using Dapper is an incorrect use of Dapper. If you wish to retrieve a `DataTable` you don't need to use Dapper at all:

```
DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
_dt.Load(dbConn.ExecuteReader("select * from tbl_dk_users where user_name like 'admin' and user_pass like '123456'"));
```

Answer (score -1):

what version of dapper are you using? you may want to downgrade it to 3.5? or make sure you are using only 1 version of dapper across your solution

Comment: What sort of answer is this, why downgrade?

Comment: because different dapper versions not compatible with each other as they vary. i am suggesting to downgrade it to lowest version across the solution

Comment: My dapper version is 1.60.6

Comment: how about the targetFramework? can you check if you are using the same versions on your solution. for example on my case
 <package id="Dapper" version="1.42" targetFramework="net35" />

Comment: Dapper version 1.60.6 and Net 4.6.1

Comment: Downgrading isn't helpful

Comment: is this the same across your solution? i am using dapper but i am using 1.42 and net 35 and it works well for me, you may want to try? this is only my suggestion

Comment: i installed version 1.42 but that version doesn't contain QueryFirstOrDefault method.